# Node's Sequelize not allowing auto-generated UUID on primary key *unless* field name is 'id'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This [Sequelize commit](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/0bfc4e31e59e6113f209b9ecd9ea0e31ebe576bd) seems to confirm that naming a primary-key 'id' makes it special. And based on my tests with the following snippet, changing the fieldname to something other than 'id' is enough for no default value to be set and, therefore, inserts fail.

`id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4, allowNull: false }`

So is there a way to keep the flexibility in naming primary key fields AND default it to a UUID?

Comment: I assume you've posted this on sequelize's issue tracker and got no answer? If not: that should be done before posting on stackoverflow. The Sequelize devs are really good at responding to issues filed against their project.

Comment: Thanks, added it here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2231

Answer (score 0):

> Question is bit too old and at that time I think that was not possible
>   , but in 2018 it is possible :) , here we go :

To define your own primary key:

```
sequelize.define('collection', {
  uid: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true // Automatically gets converted to SERIAL for postgres
  }
});

sequelize.define('collection', {
  uuid: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    primaryKey: true
  }
});
```

**[READ MORE](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/advanced/legacy.html#primary-keys)**